# Let functions bound to timers keep executing while the execution of a different function is paused on a breakpoint

Tags: javascript, debugging, browser

Consider the following example code:

```
var count = 0;

function timer()
{
    count++;
    setTimeout( timer, 1000 );
}

function listener()
{
    alert( count );  // <--- SET A BREAK POINT HERE
    count = 0;
}

timer();

document.addEventListener( 'click', listener );
```

(Fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/g2yf5vy2/ )

If a breakpoint is set where indicated (using the browser developer tools) a subsequent click on the window will invoke `listener()` and execution will stop on `alert()`.

This -of course- stops also the periodic execution of `timer()` since this JavaScript code is single thread.

The proof is that inspecting the value of `count` from the console will show always the same number.

Is there any browser debugger that let functions bound to timers or event handlers keep executing while the execution of a different function is paused on a breakpoint?

Comment: *"...since JavaScript is single thread."* JavaScript isn't single-threaded. JavaScript on browsers has one main UI thread (and optionally several background threads, via web workers).

Comment: *"If there any browser debugger that let functions binded to timers or event handlers keep executing while the execution of a different function is paused on a breakpoint?"* If there are, they violate JavaScript's run-to-completion semantics. Being debugging tools, that's probably okay. But given that the run-to-completion is inherent in the JavaScript engine (with the possible exception of SpiderMonkey, the engine in Firefox), I'd say it's unlikely you'll find one. I can't imagine *wanting* one. :-)